# Android Studio, Gradle could not find android:buildToolsVersion 3.4.0

Tags: android

I have a problem with my gradle in android studio

When I sync I get this following error:

**ERROR: Could not find com.androibuildToolsVersion d.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/androibuildToolsVersion d/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/androibuildToolsVersion d/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androibuildToolsVersion d/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androibuildToolsVersion d/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
  - http://jitpack.io/com/androibuildToolsVersion d/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
  - http://jitpack.io/com/androibuildToolsVersion d/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
Required by:
    project :

Why is this the case?

Here's my gradle file:

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.madgusto.gamingreminder"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 32
        versionName "3.12"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    [...]
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: well...in what locations did AndroidStudio search? If the dependency is not in one of these locations you missed to add a repository url for the real location.

Comment: How do we add the url? Sorry I'm really new to android

Comment: @Johnnyboy, could you please share the locations where search is done? As its not mentioned in the question and would be helpful to understand.

Comment: Ok I just edited my questions and adden

Comment: I added them in* Sorry for the typo

Comment: @MonikaKumarJethani

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> **ERROR: Could not find com.androibuildToolsVersion d.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0.

The is a **d** missing in *androibuildToolsVersion* and *d.tools.build:gradle* looks a little bit strange aswell you probably edited a file you shouln't have edited. It probably should look like *buildToolsVersion* and *com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.4.0.*
I am sorry I cannot say which one and i wasn't able to write this in the comments but perhaps you already know whichone. :)

Comment: Did you rebuild it? and added com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.4.0. because i updated the answer a few seconds ago ;)